# Vue3 ; How to make drag and drop work correctly on mobile?

Tags: mobile, vuejs3

I have designed a couple of sites with Vue3 which use elements in an n x n grid. They both work perfectly on a desktop browser, but on a mobile it's rubbish:

**Chrome:** just about works, but it's necessary to touch *and hold* an image for a second or two (until there's a tiny 'click' feedback) before it will drag.

**Firefox:** doesn't drag at all

**Safari:** drags but crashes when dropped.

The elements are defined like this:

```
      <v-img class="canDragIt"
       :draggable="true"
       @dragstart="drag($event,idString(cell.id,r,c))"
       @drop="drop($event,r,c)"
       @dragover="allowDrop($event,r,c)"
       @dblclick = "addNoTrack(r,c)"
       :src = cell.content
     >
```

I have written all the event handlers to allow swapping of images, and preventing certain images from being dragged (or dropped in certain places). As I say, it all works fine on desktop browsers.
There are several  third-party libraries for drag-and-drop on Vue etc, e.g  [vue.draggable.next](https://github.com/SortableJS/vue.draggable.next) and [sortable-js-vue3](https://github.com/MaxLeiter/sortablejs-vue3) but these are based on `sortablejs` and re-order the items that are dragged on to, which is an effect that I do not want and cause extra complications. Some have 'swap' plugins but they are difficult to use ; support is fairly up-to-date for some libraries; others are poorly unsupported or not at all.

I have also tried [DragDropTouch](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1091766/Add-support-for-standard-HTML-Drag-and-Drop-operat) but this is either incompatible with Vue/Vuetify or hasn't been tested with latest browsers (it's 7 years old).

I have tried plain `mousedown` etc:

```
:draggable="true"
@mousedown="startDrag($event,r,c)"
@mousemove="mouseDrag($event,r,c)"
@touchstart="startDrag($event,r,c)"
@touchend="touchDrag($event,r,c)"
```

and this works well on mobile and desktop BUT the drag cursor is always 'noentry' (drop not allowed) and I have failed to find a way of overcoming this (I have tried `event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed` etc, `event.target.style.cursor='move'` and `Element.setPointerCapture()` but none appear to work with Vue)

I have also tried [vue-3-touch-events](https://github.com/robinrodricks/vue3-touch-events#readme) but the events triggered don't have the `dataTransfer` property, so I cannot use my existing code for event handling.

So, is there a tried and tested way of using vue with draggable elements on mobile without using sortablejs? I'm happy to use the simple `mousedown` / `touchstart` method if I can sort out that annoying cursor!

Comment: I ended up write some code from scratch. It's at https://github.com/quilkin/DragDropLib - it's uncommented, and I can't help you much but you're welcome to have a look and use whatver bits you need.